# Is this inhomogeneous Poisson process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I asked this question in math stack exchange but since it is more related to probability and statistics, I thought I can ask here.

Consider the population growth model where $P′(t)=rP(t)$, where $P(t)$ is the population at time $t$ with the constant growth rate $r$. Modeling this as a homogeneous Poisson process, at time $t$, $P(t+1)$ can be obtained by simulating from a Poisson distribution with mean $λ=rP(t)$. So far so good.

Now, if $r$ is a function of $P(t)$ with constants $\alpha$ and $K$, such that
$$
r(t)=\alpha \log(K/P(t)),
$$
is it still a non-homogeneous Poisson process? If not what process this might follow?

If the process is not known, suppose we know $P(0)$, choosing initial $\alpha$ and $K$, can we simulate this as a homogeneous Poisson process starting with $r(0)$ and iterating $r$ and $P$ as the process evolves?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our tour, which has information for new users. 
Please add the [self-study] tag and read its wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: Dear jbowman, just a fyi - I am a biology faculty in one of the institutions in the US. I don't know what made you think that this is a homework. If you want to close this please do - but please realize that there are fields in which even experts may want to learn from other fields which they might understand a little.

Comment: Also, by the way, this is a research question that occurs when you model intra-tumor heterogeneity using Gompertz function.

Comment: My apologies!  I looked at a couple of the questions you'd posted on math and they looked like homework-type stats questions as well.  This is the sort of question that might be asked to see if someone can distinguish between a homogenous and a a non-homogenous Poisson process, which it is.

Comment: No problemo. Actually, it looks like it is more like Hawkes process since there is a stochastic component to the inhomogeneous Poisson (if it means having a deterministic time-varying rate parameter), although one can claim it is all inhomogeneous. What one cannot do is simulate using homogeneous, which I thought I can.

Comment: At time $t$, $P(t)$ is known, and it doesn't change until the next arrival, so $r(t)$ is also fixed until the next arrival.  So it seems to me that your simulation approach should work fine, since really you're going to draw the Exponential interarrival time, and after every arrival just update the rate parameter and make the next draw.

Comment: hmm...that is what I thought. But, isn't intrinsically $P(t+1)$ is dependent on $P(t)$? $r(t)$ is dependent on $P(t)$ and so the draw I make in the next iteration is not technically independent. I thought both homogeneous/inhomogeneous Poisson assumes that independence?

Comment: $P(t+1)$ is always dependent on $P(t)$, as it has to be $\geq P(t)$, but I see your point.  The simulation will work as designed, as, given $P(t)$, the time to the next arrival is independent of everything else (including $t$ itself.)   I have to admit that on reflection I doubt this (even combined with the Exponential interarrival time assumption) fulfills the requirements for an inhomogenous Poisson process, as the number of arrivals over a fixed interval won't be Poisson; more arrivals increase the probability of even more arrivals, etc.  Sorry about not thinking it through more to start.

Comment: Yes, I think more arrivals increasing the probability of even more arrivals makes it a perfect candidate for a Hawkes process, if we assume the probability will exponentially decrease over time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81242/discussion-between-jbowman-and-kasthuri).